# Firefox for Mac displaying scrollbar behind child elements

Tags: html, css, macos, firefox, scrollbar

in Firefox 25.0.1 and Firefix 26 for Mac (on Mavericks), I am running into a lot of issues with Firefox displaying the scrollbar behind child elements of divs with an overflow-y:scroll; (or auto) on them. I created a simple JS fiddle that shows this behavior (code below):
http://jsfiddle.net/barts/6y4ce/

If you start scrolling, the #toolbar div will overlap the scrollbar, which has a z-index:20 on it. If I take out the z-index then the scrollbar will correctly display over the toolbar. But if I leave the z-index and set one on the #container div, it doesn't matter if I make it a higher or lower number, the scrollbar always goes under the toolbar.

Am I missing something simple? In Safari and Chrome the scrollbars always show on top.

```
    <style type="text/css">

    * { 
        box-sizing:border-box; 
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    #container {
        width:500px;
        height:500px;
        background:#ccc;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }

    #toolbar {
        background:#efefef;
        position:relative;
        z-index:20;
        width:100%;
        padding:20px;
        height:50px;
    }

    </style>


    <div id="container">

        <div id="header">

            <h1>Test</h1>

            <div id="toolbar">

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="content">

            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>

            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>

            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>

            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>


            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>

            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>


            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>

            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>


            <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>

            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam.</p>

        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: What happened to Lorem Ipsum?

Comment: @ManofSnow, I use this program for Macs called [LittleIpsum](http://littleipsum.com/) that lets me generate different ones.  :)

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to fix this particular problem; one such way is use the `overflow-y property` in the `container` div as before, although using the other properties in the `content` div instead. Within the html you'll need to swap the positions of the divs `container` and `header`, and also nest the `content` div within the `container` div.

```
#container {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}

#content {
    background:#ccc;
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
```

[Example (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4ce/40/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. Taking the width off the container isn't really practical for what I'm using this for. 

Also, it seems like the problem persists of I take the width:100%; off of the #toolbar div. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6y4ce/40/

Comment: @BartS., You can move the width and height properties back into the container also. The important thing is having the `overflow-y:scroll` in the container and the nestng of the divs — [have a look](http://jsfiddle.net/6y4ce/46/).

Comment: @lll In your example, I only see the overflow-y:scroll that I already. And there are some issues with it... in Firefox the content area now overlaps the scrollbar and in other browsers there's a horizontal scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Make `position: relative` for parent (overflowed) element and `z-index` as much as possible, just try to set more then children elements, for example `z-index: 999999`